# How to show $\frac{300}{v} - \frac{300}{v+20} = 1.25$

Tags: quadratics

A man travels a distance of $300$ km. On his return journey his average speed increased by $20$ km/h and his journey time decreased by $1\frac{1}{4}$ hours. If $v$ is the average speed of his outward journey how can we show that:
$$\frac{300}{v} - \frac{300}{v+20} = 1.25$$
I'm very stuck.

Comment: If $v$ the average speed of his return journey, the average speed of his forward journey is $v+20$

So, $$\frac{300}v-\frac{300}{v+20}=\frac54$$

Comment: oops...$v$ is supposed to be the average speed of his outward journey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the information you have, using $\text{speed}\cdot \text{time} = \text{distance}$ you can create two equations: 
$$\text{I:}\quad v\cdot t = 300\\
\text{II:}\quad (v+20)\cdot (t-1.25) = 300$$

**Edit:**
Express $t$ from each equation, you get
$$\text{I:}\quad t = \frac{300}{v}\\
\text{II:}\quad t = \frac{300}{v+20} + 1.25$$

Now compare substitute $t$ from the first equation into the second one. 
$$\frac{300}{v} = \frac{300}{v+20} + 1.25$$
Now you only have to subtract $\frac{300}{v+20}$.

Comment: how to show that the equation in the question is true from that equation?

Comment: I edited some more explanations.

Comment: THANK YOU! I have literally torn two pages of scribbled out equations out of my maths book